# Writing to ConsoleApplication project from a different project in C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have a WinForms and a ConsoleApplication project. I start both projects at the startup and want to write "live" information to the console application FROM the WinForms app. The console app is pretty simple:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     while (true)
     {
         // This prevents the console from dying
         Console.ReadKey();
     }
  }

  public static void WriteMessage(string message)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
```

And I call the `WriteMessage` function from the WinForms app, but this doesn't work. I put a breakpoint in the WriteMessage method and it gets hit, but nothing is put on the console screen, which makes me think it's because of the while loop in `main`. I even tried putting the while loop in a different thread but still no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Consoles belong to *processes*, not Visual Studio projects

Most applications (including your WinForms app) have a hidden console.
Calling the console project's `WriteMessage()` from the WinForms process still writes to the WinForms process' console, which is why you aren't seeing anything..

Instead, you should delete the console project, then set the `Output Type` of the WinForms app (in Project Properties) to Console application.
This will make the WinForms app have a visible console, so that `Console.WriteLine` would just work.

Comment: This makes much more sense now. Thanks a lot.